# How to design a "terminal" or CLI app in Javascript for the browser? (simulate blocking I/O)

Tags: javascript

Is pretty easy to develop a CLI application when you have a blocking I/O API for it (for example PrintLn / ReadLn etc).

But I need to simulate a terminal application that runs on the browser with JS, but there the input events are async (I cannot block in the middle of a function waiting for input, preserving the state of the application).

Where I'm struggling is in the design of the event loop and the architecture of the js code. Specially considering that there will be a lot of levels of commands inside the app. I don't want to end in "callback hell". Can someone point me in some resource on how to architect this design? Thanks

Comment: Could you maybe link to some example of what you are trying to achieve ? Or maybe elaborate a little

Comment: you can `await` input if you use `async` `main`.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Promises**

1. Submit input
2. Block new input
3. Call Promise
4. Display result after Promised has been resolved
5. Release terminal for new input

---

```
// On submit line
// Pressing enter or something, and triggering the operation
function submit(myCommand) => {

  // Block terminal
  // You should write this yourself, but the terminal should be
  // blocked after input, until the response returned, so you
  // should wait for the next input after the current has resolved
  blockTerminal();

  // Send your command
  // Trigger the async Promise
  // then() is called when the operation in complete
  doSomething(myCommand).then(result => {

    // Display the result in the terminal
    // Write this function yourself
    output(result);

    // Release terminal
    // Write this yourself too. It should open the terminal
    // for new inputs
    releaseTerminal();
  })
}

// The async code that's called
// Returns a Promise
function doSomething(myCommand) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {

    // Fake a 2500ms delay
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('result')
    }, 2500)
  })
}
```

In production, you should replace the `setTimeout()` with an Ajax call, and call `resolve(response)` on success.

---

Otherwise you should take a look at [RxJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/).

It introduces Observable streams in Javascript, which are great for working with async operations. Better than Promises, but the concept is also harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You may use async/await to achieve this.

```js
function getLine(){
  return new Promise(res=>{
    document.querySelector('#GO').addEventListener('click',()=>res(document.querySelector('#STDIN').value,{once:true}))
  })
}

async function main(){
  for(let i=0;;++i){
    let line = await getLine()
    console.log(`${i}:${line}`)
  }
}

main()
```

```html
<input type="text" id="STDIN">
<input type="button" value="GO" id="GO">
```